# What is she doing, because she's certainly not "training her bottom"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

One of the lessons in the online Lingoni German course is about body parts (Körperteile). One of the body parts is *der Po*. The example sentence using *der Po* is:

> Sie trainiert ihren Po.

and the translation given is:

> She is training her bottom.

As a native English speaker, I'm sure that whatever the German sentence means, it does ***not*** match the translation given! The various uses of "to train", include training someone or something to do something:

> He trains his dog to stand on its hind legs,

training a non-human inanimate thing into a particular form

> She is training the climbing-rose over the archway
>
> He is training a bonsai elm tree  *(i.e., training an elm-tree into a bonsai form)*

and training with some sort of prepositional object

> She is training *for the marathon*.

I assume that "she" is not doing any of these things, and that the given German sentence actually corresponds to something like:

> She is strengthening her glutes (i.e. gluteal muscles)

or

> She is in training to strengthen her glutes. / **Note: NOT** *She is training her glutes*.

However, the example sentence is devoid of context other than *Körperteile*. Have I guessed the meaning of the sentence correctly, or is something else intended? Potty training of a young girl?

Comment: Yes, the German phrase refers to a workout of her butt, as it were. However you want to put that in English.

Comment: Did you try a dictionary?

Comment: Use "to exercise sth." or "work out sth." instead of "to train" to translate "*etwas* (a body part) trainieren" here. That's more adequate. Your book seems to be a bit off here. A good dictionary should mention these.

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone at Lingoni should have caught that and provided a more useful translation. These on-line courses aren't always checked in both directions by native speakers, so errors creep in. Does Lingoni have a reporting mechanism for this kind of thing?

Comment: @RDBury Although I think that the Lingoni course (and it's predecessor Youtube ... German with Jenny) are good, the material produced by new authors doesn't seem to have the quality (or, more particularly, the quality control) of the original. Attempts to point our errors have generally not been successful.

Comment: Add this to the list of 'false friends'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The German verb *trainieren* works in two ways.

1. You can train someone to do something e.g. your dog, your child, your neural net, ...

> Ich habe ein neuronales Netz zur Bilderkennung trainiert

> Ich trainiere meinen Hund, sodass er mir morgens die Zeitung bringt.

> Ich trainiere eine Gruppe im Tennis.

(note that for potty-training you would use the verb *beibringen*.)

2. It refers to a workout of your muscles or your body / brain in general

> Ich trainiere meinen Bauch, Rücken, Po ... meine Arme, Beine, Schultern

> Ich trainiere für den Marathon, für den Schwimmwettbewerb, für die Matheolympiade

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer and for treating the questions seriously.I don't know who voted to close the question but I doubt they actually ***checked*** that the answer was available from a dictionary. I looked at the Collins German English dictionary which did not suggest any useful translation. "She" was clearly "coaching her bottom" "practising her bottom" ... or doing any of the other things that Collins seems to suggest.

Comment: @user02814, if you checked the dictionary then you can include the results in your question.
https://www.dwds.de/wb/trainieren  "übertragen: etw. durch Üben verbessern;
Beispiele:
sein Gedächtnis trainieren" seems to be not that dissimilar to me.